# OpenGL - Sweep Representations

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, modeling, mesh

I have a set of points, confined to a two dimensional coordinate plane, specifically the first and fourth quadrants (positive x values). I am able to draw a line through these points.

I can also draw these points in 3D space, in another window, as a line. How would I go about sweeping them around an axis, say, Y, so that I can achieve a 3D mesh? I believe the usual example for this is using points to create a line in Maya, to create a goblet or the like.

I can't seem to find much by Googling the term "Sweep Representation", which is what my textbook refers to this process as. I'm just seeking some kind of thought process, or guidelines to, um, guide me!

Comment: The concept you're looking for is generally called a "swept surface" or "extrusion" or "surface of revolution" (when specifically rotating about an axis).

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117084/opengl-how-to-lathe-a-2d-shape-into-3d/4117489#4117489

Comment: Yes Drew, that pretty much explains how to generate the points.  However you still need to generate the triangles or line segments to connect them to each other.

Comment: @Robinson: The actual triangles are luckily pretty trivial, once you know the points, since the object is very, very regular. Two adjacent points from each swept segment with the same points (that is, points with the same array indices) from the next one form a quad, which is really just two triangles. Turning these and their in-column neighbours into a tristrip is trivial too, only having the entire object in a single strip requires a 1-2 minutes of thought (but is not complicated, either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but the overriding principle is to rotate the original line around some axis, and then emit vertices from the current line to the next line in order to generate triangles, remembering to "close" the shape by joining the last line with the first.

Personally I would generate a vertex buffer and an index buffer.  I would rotate the line N times around the Y axis, storing each rotated line's points into the vertex buffer.

Then, the next part of the algorithm would generate indices for one or more line strips (multiple line strips are easier because otherwise you'd need to create degenerate triangles to go from one strip to the next)

So, given that you have a vertex buffer V, a number of points in your original line P and a number of lines N, you can simply iterate across, generating triangle strips by emitting index I and index I + P, P * N times.  You then render N triangle strips given the vertex buffer and index buffer.

If you want to be clever, you can just store an index buffer with a single strips indices in, and add P to the base vertex index each time you render.  Be careful with highly tessellated meshes with lots of indices.  Some cards have a max vertex index which is 65535, others have one only slightly larger.

I hope that made sense!

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure the final image you want to achieve, but from what i understand, you have a "line" (is this a straight line? a curved "line"? - not clear about this) - and you want to revolve them around some axis so that it creates some sort of 2 dimensional "mesh" like a disc or cone or something?

you could simply try glRotatef(a,x,y,z) where:

"a" is the angle you want to rotate and 
 is the vector around which you are rotating.

thus, if you want to plot the figure 10 times around the y axis then it might look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    float da = 2.0*3.14/10.0
    plotLine(); // function for plotting the line once in 3 space
    glRotatef(da, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

this will plot the line, rotate the entire figure by a small amount, then plot it again (this will repeat 10 times so that the original line is plotted 10 times around an axis - creating the "mesh" that i believe you are trying to achieve

Comment: That will indeed repeat the "line" with respect to the Y axis, but that won't connect the points horizontally will it? Won't it just be a bunch of "vertical" line segments in space? I need to also bring the points together "horizontally".

Comment: Also, the "line" is just a bunch of user defined points connected together, via GL_LINE_STRIP.

Comment: I see what you mean. So the above works, you simply need them all to be connected horizontally as well?